# Best way to delete common data from two large tables in oracle?

Tags: oracle11g

I am trying to delete data from table A where matching records from table B. both A, B tables are large tables each is of size around 80GB. Could you please suggest me the best approach to complete the deletion of data from table A? The sql which I am using is:

```
PROCEDURE del_procedure (col_value_from_B      INTEGER)
   IS
      sql_stmt   VARCHAR2 (2000);
      col_val_from_A    INTEGER := 0;     

   BEGIN
      SELECT MAX (col1) into col_val_from_A               FROM table_B b
          WHERE b.col < col_value_from_B;      

      sql_stmt :=
            'DELETE FROM table_A a'
         || 'WHERE a.col1 <= '
         || col_val_from_A
         || ' and rownum<= 500000 ';

      LOOP
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt;

         IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0
         THEN
            EXIT;
         END IF;

         COMMIT;
      END LOOP;

   EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS
      THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (SQLCODE || SQLERRM);
         RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20002, SQLCODE || SQLERRM);
   END col_val_from_A;
```

Comment: Where is tableA mentioned in your code? Also, I would remove the entire exception block, if I were you. Or at the very least, replace the `raise_application_error` with just `raise`. (And you realise that `SQLERRM` already contains the `SQLCODE`, right? So no need to append it again!). What's wrong with a straightforward single delete statement? And why is your delete statement written as dynamic sql, when you could easily write it as a static statement?

Comment: Modified the sql which I used to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's a jolly good reason* I'd just do:

```
DELETE FROM table_A a
WHERE a.col1 <= (SELECT MAX (col1)
                 FROM   table_B b
                 WHERE  b.col < col_value_from_B);
```

*which does not include "this statement causes the UNDO tablespace to run out!"; that just means you need to increase your UNDO tablespace accordingly. (The only exception to this, IMHO, is if it's a one-off or rarely performed process. In your case, given you're writing a procedure for it, I'm guessing that it's going to be done regularly.)

Comment: Yes. I am going to run this regulary like once in a quarter or so. But the same sql I have written and tested and it took more than 24 hrs and at the end it got failed with undovable mermory error. So looking for better and diff approach to do the same.